# How to convert the first letter into upper case?

Tags: c

I am trying to design a simple program which will ask the username, but when the entered username is later used, it should have its first letter uppercase.
How can I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char name[30];
    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    char n = toupper(name);
    printf("Hello %s. Could you tell us a bit about yourself?", n);
}
```

Comment: The library function `toupper` converts the case of a single character. If you want to uppercase the whole string you can use `strupr(name);` although I don't think this is a standard library function, but an extension.

Comment: toupper takes a single character (actually int), but you've passed in an array of char. You need to pass only the first character from the array to toupper, replace the original in the array, and then pass the array to printf.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, the title of your question is important, because people look at a title like you had and ignore your question. Try to use a meaningful title. I changed the title of your question, this is how you should set your title of your question.

Comment: Save time and enable all compiler warnings.  It should catch beginner  errors like  `char n = toupper(name);` and `printf("Hello %s. ...", n);`

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong

```
char n = toupper(name);
```

The function `toupper` expects a single character, you are passing a pointer
to a character.

The correct version:

```
char n = toupper(name[0]);
```

This line is also wrong

```
printf("Hello %s. Could you tell us a bit about yourself?", n);
```

The format specifier `%s` expects a string passed by a pointer of `char`, you
are passing a single character. The compiler should have warned you about it.
Don't ignore the compiler warnings.

You want to change the first letter in the buffer. So you have to save the
converted letter back into the buffer.

```
name[0] = toupper(name[0]);
printf("Hello %s. Could you tell us a bit about yourself?", name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Just a question, what does the bracket operator [ ] mean over here.

Comment: @farizz145 in the definition `char name[30];` it is the length of the array. In `toupper(name[0])` it specifies the *index* to one element of the aray, here: the first element since in C arrays are indexed from element `0`.

Comment: @farizz145 that is C basics of how to access arrays. I'd suggest that you pick up a book about C and start reading from the beginning, otherwise you won't have any fun while coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you have collected the name, you can proceed as follows:

```
if (name[0] >= 'a' && name[0] <= 'z')
{
    name[0] -= 0x20;
}
printf("Hello %s. Could you tell us a bit about yourself?", name);
```

The assumptions are:

1 - you have the name
2 - it begins in first character of the character array
3 - the name is in ASCII / English 7-bit characters

Aside from that, see the other answer by Pablo - you've made several errors.

Comment: While this code is correct, please don't teach "black magic" to beginners, that's way beyond the point of understanding right now. The OP might not even understand what `'a'`really means and what `0x20`.

Comment: `'a'` is a bit less black magic than `97` but you can use library functions such as `islower` and `isalpha`. In the question `toupper` takes care of everything, but was wrong in *how* the code uses `toupper`.

Comment: I was sort of trying to encourage a little insight into what ASCII is and how it is arranged; hence the intentionally mixed approach: 'a' and 0x20.

Comment: `name[0] = name[0] - 'a' + 'A';` would provide better insight and coding than `name[0] -= 0x20;`.

Comment: @Pablo That isn't black magic. It's the most efficient way to do it and should be how toupper() is implemented (and I don't really think it's difficult for beginners to understand). However I agree with you that the person who answered the question should have explained how his example works.

Comment: `toupper`, like many of the standard library's text functions, accounts for locale. So, no, that should not be the way `toupper` is implemented.

Comment: @Cppplus1 Perhaps I used the wrong words. I know that the difference between 'a' and 'A' is the fifth bit, I understand why it may be the most efficient way, but that was not my point. I wanted to express that we sometimes should try to see through the OP's perspective. For a person that struggles with a concept like accessing arrays, this might be "black magic". And yes, teaching new concepts to a beginner is a good thing (that's why my answers tend to be very long), but an explanation of why this workes and how this works would make this answer even better.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer which attempts to get your code working with minimal changes.

Change

```
toupper(name);
```

to

```
toupper(*name);
```

in order to correctly use only the first character of the name, which is what `name`, interpreted as pointer to `char` points to.

Then change

```
printf("Hello %s. Could you tell us a bit about yourself?", n);
```

tp

```
printf("Hello %c%s. Could you tell us a bit about yourself?", n, name+1);
```

in order to print first the modified first character and then the rest of the name, employing pointer arithmetic (again interpreting `name` as pointer to char) to skip the first character.